# How do you use a public variable in a Class Module?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a Class Module to make a collection of save buttons all do the same thing.  But when I try to get them to run a sub that requires a variable I can't get the variable passed to them.

Edited using @Teasel's advice about properties.  The problem seems to be the Let Property is not allowing me to set the variable from Module1.

Class1

```
Public WithEvents SaveBtn As MSForms.CommandButton

Dim currentrow As Long

Private Sub SaveBtn_Click()
     SendMessage
     `Even if I just have it Msgbox currentrow it returns 0
End Sub

Property Let GetRow(myrow As Long)
    currentrow = myrow
End Property

Property Get GetRow() As Long
    GetRow = currentrow
End Property
```

Module1

```
`Trying to send the value into the Class using Let
Private Sub SendRow_Click()
Module1.GetRow = 22
End Sub

`Trying to Get the value back from the Class
Public Sub SendMessage()
    Dim therow As Long
    therow = Module1.GetRow
    `I get the "Method or Data Member not found" error in the line above
    MsgBox therow
End Sub
```

UserForm1

```
`This part works fine
Dim colSaveButtons As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim i As Long
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
Dim obEvents As Class1

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
        For i = 0 To 5
            If ctl.Name = "btnSavePage" & i Then
                Set obEvents = New Class1
                Set obEvents.SaveBtn = ctl
                colSaveButtons.Add obEvents
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post all parts of the code necessary to reproduce the issue. Check [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's no code there which outputs or returns anything?

Comment: You've given us a pretty scant amount of code. What I will say is that you've defined `var`, the argument to `GenericSave`, as a boolean. If you try to pass anything other than a logical true or false to it, you'll get results that you might not expect.

Comment: sorry, I'll add more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "CurrentRow" field to your class module:

```
Public WithEvents SaveBtn As MSForms.CommandButton
Public CurrentRow As Long '<< add this

Private Sub SaveBtn_Click()
     SendMessage CurrentRow 
End Sub
```

In your loop:

```
...
If ctl.Name = "btnSavePage" & i Then
    Set obEvents = New Class1
    obEvents.CurrentRow = 10 'or whatever...
    Set obEvents.SaveBtn = ctl
    colSaveButtons.Add obEvents
End If
...
```

And your `SendMessage` method:

```
Public Sub SendMessage(CurrentRow As Long)
     MsgBox "This works"
End Sub
```

Comment: Spoke too soon.  It works if I set the value of CurrentRow in the UserForm_Initialize sub.  But if I try to set it in a different Userform sub or a different module it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you need to adjust the value of the variable after creating the objects then you'll need a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two differents ways to achieve that.

---

**1. Public Property**

To simple access your variable's value you need a Get property and to set its value you need a Let property.

In your Module:

```
'Your module private variable
Dim nameOfYourModuleVariable As String

...

'Set property to assign a value to your variable
Public Property Let nameOfYourProperty(value As String)
    nameOfYourModuleVariable = value
End Property

'Get property to return the value of your variable
Public Property Get nameOfYourProperty() As String
    nameOfYourProperty = nameOfYourModuleVariable
End Property
```

You can then use it like this:

```
'Set the value
MyModule.nameOfYourProperty = "foo"

'Get the value
MyModule.nameOfYourProperty
```

I highly recommend to use properties to do such things however you can also simply set your variable as `public` as shown in point 2.

---

**2. Public Variable**

Define your variable to be **public** so you can access it from everywhere.

In your Module:

```
Public nameOfYourVariable As String
```

Get or set the value from another module:

```
'Set the value
MyModule.nameOfYourVariable = "foo"

'Get the value
MyModule.nameOfYourVariable
```

Comment: The Public Property goes in the Class Module correct?  So if I wanted to get the variable into a sub in "Module1" I would use `Module1.nameOfYourGetter =`  Don't I need a Let Property to get the variable originally in the UserForm, into the Class Module?

Comment: @bigbucky Indeed, I posted a Getter only but to give a value to your variable through a property you'll need a Let property. In your example you seemed to only wanted to access it so I didn't post a Let Property. I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: I see.  I don't think I need a Let property then.  But when I try to Get the "currentrow" variable into Module1 it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @bigbucky There are two things missing in your code. First, you need to declare your **currentrow** variable in your module with something like `Dim currentrow As Long` and last things missing is your variable initalisation, you never set its value so you can't really use it in your class. If you want to set its value from your class then use the Let Property (as shown in my answer) or directly set its value from your module with `currentrow = 123`.

Comment: I set the value in the UserForm module but I can’t get it in Module1.  I declare it in Module1 but I’ve tried declaring it in different modules and it doesn’t seem to help.  I cant seem to get the value from the UserForm when I call the Module1 sub using the Click sub in the Class Module.

Comment: @bigbucky please complete your question with all of your code so I can see what you do wrong